# Irradiance for a tracking surface

Tags: python, pvlib

I have collect solar irradiance data (GHI) from ERA5 satellite. I would like to know what functions do I have to use to get the irradiance for a tracking surface because to my modules are trackers.

Hope you can help me
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in tracking part of pvlib u can find the function for get_tracking_irradiance .
If it does not work for your project u can define a function for it using pvarrays and etc...

Comment: Thanks. I can not find a funcitio with that exact name "get_tracking_irradiance". I found one that is "SingleAxisTracker.get_irradiance" but this requieres a lote of parameters (solar_zenith, solar_azimuth, dni, ghi,dhi..) and I only have GHI